# Halting problem logic must be wrong

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques, halting-problem

I think that I have found an issue with the proof of the halting problem, which would cause the entire proof to be invalid.

To ensure I understand, here is Turing's proof of the halting problem being unsolvable.

### Proof:

Assume the function $h(x,y)$ determines whether the function $y(x)$ halts on input x, $h(x,y)$ returns True, or 1 if $y(x)$ halts, otherwise it returns False or 0.

Given that the function $h(x,y)$ exists, it must be possible to create a new function, $h'(x)$, which is just $h(x,x)$. In essence, $h'(x)$ determines if the program $x()$ halts when run with itself (encoded in the form of a number).

If $h'(x)$ also exists, then again, a new function $H(x)$ can be created. $H(x)$ in pseudo code is:

```
Def H(x) 

    If h'(x) == True: 

Loop forever 

    Otherwise: 

Return()
```

Now when $H$ is run with itself as an input – $H(H)$ - a paradox is created:

If $H(H)$ will halt, then $H$ run with itself as an input must loop, but that is the original statement

Otherwise if $H(H)$ loops, then $H$ run on itself must halt, which is a contradiction.

Hence $H(x)$ cannot exist, and by extension $h(x)$ cannot exist

### Disproof of the proof:

If we assume that the logic in Turing's proof is correct, then we can do this:

Assume the function $l(x,y)$ determines whether $y(x)$ takes more than n, where n is any number, seconds to compute.

Symmetrically to $h(x,y)$ going to $h'(x)$, $l'(x)$ can also be created from $l(x,y)$, where $l'(x)$ = $l(x,x)$.

Finally, exactly the same as in Turing's proof, $L(x)$ can also exist. $L(x)$ will take more than n seconds to compute if $l'(x)$ returns False, and otherwise will take less than n seconds. $L(x)$ does the opposite of $x(x)$.

If $L(x)$ does exist, then $L(L)$ can be run, and results in a paradox the same way that $H(H)$ does.

But the function $l(x,y)$ is possible to create, by simply timing the function $y(x)$. It may be that some adjustments are needed to fix the way $l(x,y)$ works, e.g there is an inherent time associated with the function so  you need to subtract a number, but the function should work.

Edit:
Because it is confusing as to exactly what $l(x,y)$ is, I should clarify. What the function $l(x,y)$ is is completely irrelevant to whether the proof works. I chose the steps taken or the time taken because it is similar to the original problem, but an easy function might be something like if the first character of x and y are both in the first half of the alphabet. That would still work with the proof.

Not only this, but the logic can be extended to any meta-program, and because  most programs could be divided into 2 programs, the same way that $x^2 + 8x + 16$ can be divided into $f(g(x))$ where $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x + 4$. Turing's proof, if correct, would also prove that any program is not able to be created, which is evidently false, hence the proof must be false.
Is this incorrect?

Comment: A matter of common sense: had it been so easy to disprove Turing's argument, that would be known since then. Hence you are essentially asking where your logic is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is exactly what im asking - let me make it clear, i do not believe that i am able to disprove the argument, but i have been stuck on this for almost a year and just want to know where i am wrong.

Comment: Please replace in your argument all references by analogy by explicit descriptions. In particular: explicitly define $L$, explicitly argue how a paradox is reached with $L (do not say "exactly the same as in Turing's proof" and "and results in a paradox the same way that" because it is not **exactly** the same).

Comment: And also, all you have discovered is that simulation cannot speed up computation, i.e., your argument says something about how fast $l$ can work.

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis of $L(L)$ is not complete.

Indeed, if we assume $L(L)$ loops this implies that $L(L)$ runs in less that $n$ steps, thus $L(L)$ does not loop. Hence *our assumption* $L(L)$ loops is false. We conclude $L(L)$ must halt.
Now if we assume $L(L)$ halts in $<n$ steps, we again get a contradiction (because $L(L)$ loops). Thus $L(L)$ can not halt in $<n$ steps.

Our results is that $L(L)$ halts in $\geq n$ steps. This is entirely consistent with the definition of $L$. Math is not yet broken.

Comment: Apologies, i should have specified. $L(x)$ would take more than n seconds if $x(x)$ takes less, and $L(x)$ would take less than n seconds if $x(x)$ takes more. It isnt the same as $H(x)$ where we use infinite loops, but instead using the condition $l(x,y)$ checks for. So if L(L) takes more than n seconds, then L(L) takes less than n seconds. If you want to be really precise, we could instead have the definition being $< n$ seconds or $>= n$ seconds, which makes sure the 2 criteria have no overlap.

Comment: @Mercury Please write out your definition of $L$ in your post. Because your comment with if "$L(L)$ takes more than $n$ steps then $L(L)$ less than $n$ steps" only makes sense if you know how many steps $l(x,y)$ takes, but you don't. So if $l(x,y)$ takes more than $n$ steps, the contradiction falls apart. In fact what you prove is that you can not determine if a TM halts in $n$ steps using less than $n$ steps.

Comment: I have edited my post with an update. The key idea is that what $l(x,y)$ actually is is completely irrelevant, you are focusing on the details of how $l(x,y)$ works when it doesnt really matter.

Comment: @Mercury $H$ breaks the Halting decider because it constructs a situation where the halting decider cannot be right. You can't use the same logic with an arbitrary function without specifying how you intend to force the function to fail. (See my answer for more in-depth explanation.)

Comment: I don't like the fact this is shown by contradiction, when it can easily be shown directly, and deliver more intuition about why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user253751 I'm not aware of a direct proof. I looked into your answer but you just state that you can't know if a TM halts in $n$ steps without running it for $n$ steps without a proof. If you know a resource with a direct proof please share.

Comment: @plshelp The supposed "$n$-halt decider" described in the question is one which runs the TM for $n$ steps and then checks if it has halted. Okay, using more abstract reasoning you can prove there's no such decider at all, but I think it helps the asker more to see why their specific one doesn't work. Maybe both are good answers. Idk

Comment: @user253751 Ahh, ok, for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Using "seconds" is not very well defined, so I'll use the usual "steps" instead.

The typical strategy creating a machine for $l$ is to have it simulate $y(x)$ for up to $n$ steps. If the simulation finishes, then it returns true, otherwise it returns false. If you try to diagonalize against this in the same way as the halting problem, you then get:

```
L(x) =
  if l(L,x)
  then <take more than n steps>
  else halt
```

This does not work, though. The way that $l$ works takes steps (or time, if you prefer) itself. In fact, simulation of one step takes *more* than one step, generally (it could just waste $n$ steps, too). So what happens is that $l(x,L)$ simulates $L(x)$ (which runs $l(x,L)$ ...) for $n$ steps. By doing this, it has used *more* than $n$ steps, so $L$ has, too, and the logic can no longer do anything to use fewer than $n$ steps, because halting immediately *still* results in a running time of more than $n$ steps.

Incidentally, it still doesn't work if you try to make it more like the halting problem: can a machine decide $l(x,y)$ in fewer than $n$ steps? If you try to diagonalize, then you can't rule out the possibility that the machine for $l$ takes $n-1$ steps to decide $L(L)$ fails, which ensures that $L(L)$ takes $n$ or more steps. The difference is that you can approximate $n$ very closely by a smaller finite number. But no halting computation, no matter how lengthy, approximates not-halting this way, so that just one or two more steps tips over into not-halting.

This doesn't mean that a machine *can* decide in fewer than $n$ steps if arbitrary other machines complete in fewer than $n$ steps. but it means that the diagonal argument doesn't work to rule it out.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Although i see your point and agree with your assessment, i think you are missing the overarching concept of my post. The specific function l(x,y) is unimportant, the only thing which matters is that l(x,y) 1) takes in a function and and input and 2) is easily verifiable. l(x,y) could have been any number of functions, such as does the first character of y and x sit in the first half of the alphabet. I could even restrict the set of ys and xs and get something such as: y is a program which 7 to a number, x is a positive number below 10 and the proof would follow.

Comment: Clearly it _is_ important what specific function $l$ is, because the example you first chose causes the proof to not work. "Add 7 to a number" is an example where the proof will work, because it is an instance of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). What matters is whether $l$ is trying to decide something about the _description_ of $y$, or something _finite_ about its execution details, vs. trying to decide something about the function or language it (eventually) calculates when executed completely, which is independent of the above (finite) details.

Comment: So you are telling me that adding 7 to a number is a function which is impossible? How can that be - I can already create that program in python or whatever language so how does that make sense?

Comment: No, what is impossible is for $l$ to reliably decide whether $y$ is a machine that adds $7$ to $x$. That can follow the structure of the halting problem proof and actually work. $l$ adding $7$ (to what? It has two arguments) does not.

Comment: If we define l(x,y) as determining if y(x) is > 10, and define y as being a function which adds 7 to x, the logic of the proof would indicate that l(x,y) is not a function which can exist. We can restrict the space of inputs anyway we want - it doesnt change the proof.

Comment: $l(x,y)$ deciding if $y(x) > 10$ is another instance of Rice's theorem. This doesn't mean that _all_ $l$ work. The diagonal argument also doesn't show that the problem isn't _semi_-decidable. E.G. you can write a machine that will recognize that if $y$ is the machine that (efficiently) adds $7$ to its input, and $x$ is an encoding of $4$, then $y(x)$ computes an encoding of a number greater than $10$. What the diagonal argument shows is that there is _some_ machine that cannot be correctly classified.

Answer (score 1):

If $l'(x)$ returns false (meaning $x(x)$ does not halt within $n$ seconds) - by running $x(x)$ for $n$ seconds and observing whether it halted - then it necessarily takes more than $n$ seconds to do so.

It's impossible to make a program that runs $l'(x)$ and then halts in less than $n$ seconds if $l'(x)$ returns false, because $l'(x)$ already takes more than $n$ seconds, and the computer which runs this program is not equipped with a time machine.

Your program $L(anything)$ **always** takes longer than $n$ seconds.

If you had a time machine you might be able to make this work, but then again, if you had a time machine you could also solve Turing's halting problem and become world-famous.

Comment: In regards to your first point, it may take a time to perform the function, but there are ways of adjusting the output for $L(x)$ to give a uniform time. And as i said in the edit to my post, the exact function $l(x,y)$ is irrelevant to the point.

Comment: You claim without proof that the functioning of $l$ is irrelevant.  This is false.  If $l(x, y)$ measures how long it takes to run $x(y)$ *by running it*, there is no way to define $L$ (because by the time it knows how long it's supposed to run for, it's already been too long).  
 (If you claim that $l(x, y)$ computed how fast $x(y)$ completes *in less time than it takes to run $x(y)$, the proof goes through; this finding is indeed impossible to define.)

Comment: If $l(x, y)$ checks if the first letter of the code is in the first half of the alphabet for both $x$ and $y$, it's impossible to define $L$, because the you cannot have $L$ change its own code.  . Neither of your examples of $l$ allow you to define $L$, so clearly what $l$ does matters.

Comment: @Mercury Can you make a program $l(x,y)$ that calculates whether $x(y)$ runs for $n$ seconds, without taking $n$ seconds? If you make it take a uniform time, the uniform time will be longer than $n$ seconds

Comment: @user253751 I would assume you just subtract the uniform time from the function - e.g y(x) takes 10 secs, l(y,x) for any y(x) takes 3 secs, total is 13 so y(x) would be 10.

Comment: @Mercury Your answer makes no sense. Can you make that program, or can't you?

Answer (score 0):

In Turing's proof, $H$ is a function that is obviously computable if $h$ (The putative halting decider function) is computable. The fact that $H$ causes a halting decider to "trip up" is a fundamental aspect of the proof – but conversely, that $H$ uses a putative halting decider is a fundamental aspect of the proof. You do not create the same paradox with arbitrary other functions.

Importantly, Turing's proof of the undecidability of the Halting problem is a proof by contradiction. He demonstrated a situation where the assumption of an universal halting decider does not have a correct answer. If you intend to use the same proof to demonstrate other functions are uncomputable – or as in your case, that the proof itself is flawed and that the Church-Turing thesis is wrong in that there exist intuitively computable functions that cannot be represented by Turing Machines – you must preserve the contradiction.

For a very simple example to contrast with the Halting problem plugged in the same proof frame, let $fastHalt(M)$ determining whether the Turing Machine $M$ immediately halts when run on an empty tape. (This is a special case of your function $l$, incidentally)

Now, $fastHalt$ is intuitively computable and hence there is a Turing Machine that is capable of it. If we create a function $F$ that uses $fastHalt$ similarly to Turing's proof, do we get a contradiction? As pseudocode:

```
def F(x):
    if fastHalt(x):
        loop forever
    else:
        halt
```

Is there a contradiction? Only if $fastHalt(F) = \mathsf{TRUE}$ . In that case, $F(F)$ would indeed loop forever, so we can conclude that $fastHalt(F) = \mathsf{FALSE}$ which makes sense, given $F$ cannot be represented as an immediately halting Turing Machine.

Let us fix an $n$ and return to your original function: $l'(x) = \mathsf{TRUE}$ if $x$ takes more than $n$ steps (preferable in analysis over the more chaos-dependent seconds!) to compute before halting or diverging, $\mathsf{FALSE}$ otherwise. Thereby you get this program:

```
def L(x):
    if l'(x):  //program finishes slow or never
        loop forever
    else:  //program finishes fast
        halt
```

. Does $L(L)$ force a contradiction? No: if $l'(L) = \mathsf{TRUE}$ this is entirely consistent with the outcome of the computation not halting. If $l`(L) = \mathsf{FALSE}$, this is likewise consistent with the outcome of the computation halting. It gets more interesting if you reverse the logic:

```
def L'(x):
    if NOT l'(x):  //program finishes fast
        loop forever
    else:  //program finishes slow or never
        halt
```

This gets us closer to the type of contradiction Turing's proof uses, but falls short of disproving the existence of $l'$: similarly to $fastHalt$, the outcome of $l'(L) = \mathsf{FALSE}$ ($L'(L')$ taking $n$ or fewer steps to compute) is the only case that creates a contradiction, while the outcome where $l'(L') = \mathsf{TRUE}$ creates no contradiction. In essence, what your example proves is the impossibility of a decider that determines whether a Turing Machine halts in $n$ or fewer steps without itself requiring more than $n$ steps to compute.

For one final demonstration, let's try something that doesn't use machines's running time at all and instead does something more tangible. Let $sign(M) = \mathsf{TRUE}$ iff $M$ halts with a single $1$ on the tape when $M$ is run on an empty tape.

Can we spin $sign(M)$ into a contradiction? Let's try:

```
def S(x):
    if sign(x):
        replace the 1 on the tape with a 0
        halt
    else:
        output 1 on the tape
        halt
```

Does running $S(S)$ on the tape create a contradiction similarly to Turing's halting proof? Turns out it does! If $sign(S)$ is $\mathsf{TRUE}$, $S(S)$ should halt with a $1$ on the tape, but the $1$ is replaced by a $0$. if $sign(S)$ is $\mathsf{FALSE}$, $S(S)$ should end without a $1$ on a tape but $1$ is output before halting. It follows that $sign(M)$ is not computable – a result that should not surprise a reader familiar with [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I think that you missed how exactly $L(x)$ is defined to work. In your fixed pseudo code for $L'(x)$, you use the same logic as $H(x)$, with halting or not halting. Because of this, $L'(x)$ only produces a contradiction in one state, but $L'(x)$ should be viewed as relative to $l(x,y)$, with taking more than n or less than n steps. At least i think that that is what you are saying, if i have misunderstood then please correct me .

Comment: I dont think i understand why you say that there is a contradiction in only one case.

Comment: @Mercury Does it make a difference if I replace "loop forever" with "do something that takes more than $n$ steps"? from the point of view of $l(x, y)$ they are the same thing: a program that fails to terminate in the "allotted" $n$ steps.

Comment: If $l'(L) = TRUE$, then $L(L)$ finished slow. That then implies that $l'(L) = False$, because L(L) does the opposite. I dont see how the other scenario would have a contradiction but his one wouldnt. The logic seems identical in both cases.

Comment: @Mercury If $l'(L) = \mathsf{TRUE}$ $L$ loops forever and therefore takes more than $n$ steps to compute – it doesn't imply $l'(L) = \mathsf{FALSE}$ in any way. Do you mean the other function, $L'$?

Comment: Yes I do (In my proof i think the function L(x) is actually the same as your L'(x), but i poorly articulated that)

Comment: @Mercury For $L'(L')$, if $l'(L') = \mathsf{TRUE}$ the computation halts after taking more than $n$ steps – there is no contradiction.

Comment: Sorry if i am being stupid, but surely the logic goes:
$L'(L')$ == if $l'(L') = True$, take less then n seconds.
so then the inside - L'(L') must take more then n seconds. What am i missing?

Comment: @Mercury Why does, in your mind, $l'(L') = \mathsf{TRUE}$ imply that $L'(L')$ takes less than $n$ seconds/steps/etc?

Comment: $l'(x) = True$ iff x(x) takes more than n seconds/steps. $l'(x) = l(x,x)$ which is asking does $x(x)$ take more then n secs/steps. so $l'(L')$  is asking does $L'(L')$ take more then n secs/steps, which then hence saying if $l'(L')$ is true, then it will take less than n steps/sec otherwise take more. That then is asking about $L'(L')$ and so on and so forth, leading to the conclusion that $L'(L')$ takes both < n steps and also take > n steps.

Comment: @Mercury "which then saying if $l(L')$ is true, then it will take less than n steps/secs" this is the part that does not follow. Note that the instruction in the code for this case is "halt", not "travel backwards in time and then halt".

Comment: It is nothing to do with whether it did or did not, all that i am saying is that $L'(L')$ halting implies that $L'(L')$ does not halt. This is exactly the same as in the original halting problem, there is no travelling back in time or anything.

Comment: @Mercury Again, *why*? You keep repeating that implication, but you haven't said a single thing to justify it.

Comment: Alright, lets expand $L'(L')$. (sorry i cant work out the code syntax in the comments)
`
return if $l'(L')$
else take longer than n
`
further expanded:
`
return if $l(L',L')$
else take longer than n
'
again:
`
return if $L'(L')$ takes longer than n
else: take longer than n 
`
So if it has returned, (aka taken less than n), then $L'(L')$ takes longer than n
if it has taken longer than n, then $L'(L')$ takes less than n
contradictions
I dont know how i can elaborate more than that.

Comment: @Mercury "So it has returned (aka taken less than $n$)"  <-- no, it did not take less time than $n$ and that's what I've been trying to tell you. Simulation cannot speed up computation (which your example proves).

Comment: fine, but as i have been saying you can then modify $L'$ to return if it has taken less time than n +1 or n+10 or 2n or whatever - point is you can restructure the function so it takes off the time inherent to the functions own processes

Comment: @Mercury You need to be more specific in constructing this workaround. Perhaps you should just ask it as a new question because all four answers have already demonstrated your original example does not work and modifying the question to address inconsistencies is making the whole discussion hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of the halting problem is missing an essential assumption, which may be confusing you: it is essential to assume that $h$ *always halts*, i.e., that $h(x, y)$ does not have to run $x(y)$ in order to return.  If you remove this assumption, the proof no longer works.  If you can find the exact spot and reason that the proof breaks if you remove this assumption, I expect you'll also see why your modifications don't work.